# pyinstaller for python 2.7.9 get executable that when ran just flashes on screen

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, pywin32

Hi I installed pyinstaller and pywin32 64 bit version to get an .exe. 
I did get a .exe built, but when I double click on it, it just flashes on the screen and closes. I used this as a setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['BP.py'])
```

The script BP.py asks the user to input some values and make some plots.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Below is the code

Code for BP.py is below

```
##
##BP.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np





# A function to plot the lines

def plot_lines(x,y,colors,j):


    ax = plt.subplot(2,2,j)


    for i in range(len(colors)):
        plt.plot(x,y[i],colors[i])





def plot_setup():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.grid(True)


def Max_avg(row,col,x,colors,ao1,ao2,j,a_list):

    for a in a_list:

        i = 0
        y_a1 = np.zeros((row,col))
        y_a2 = np.zeros((row,col))
        y = np.zeros((row,col))

        for ao1_v,ao2_v in zip(ao1,ao2):

            y_a1[i] = 3*x**2
            y_a2[i] = 5*x
            y[i] = np.add(y_a1[i],y_a2[i])
            i = i+1

        plot_lines(x,y,colors,j)`enter code here`
        j = j+1


def main():
    x1 = -10
    x2 = 10
    numpts = 100
    x = np.linspace(x1,x2,numpts,endpoint=True)
    col = len(x)
#    a_list = [-1.7,-5]
    print "Please enter a list of coefficients seperated by a white space."
    string_input = raw_input()
    a_list = string_input.split()
    a_list = [int(a) for a in a_list]
    ao1 = (-5.0,2.0)
    ao2 = (1.0,10.0)
    col_plt = 2
    colors = ['b','g']
    j = 1

    plot_setup()

    Max_avg(2,col,x,colors,ao1,ao2,j,a_list)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you post your script here?

Comment: @Junaos code has been placed. Thanks